# ASP.NET passing HTML input files via post from classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, html, asp-classic, upload, input

I'm in the process of migrating code from a [classic ASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) site to an [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) site.  One problem that I'm running into is an `<input type="file" name="upload"/>` form field.

```
    <form
      id="classicASPform"
      method="post"
      EncType="Multipart/Form-Data"
      action="http://domain2/formReciver.aspx">
        <input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" /><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="save" class="button" value="Save" />
        <input type="reset" id="reset" class="button" value="Reset" />
    </form>
```

When I try to access the data on the ASP.NET page I'm getting 0 for Request.Files.Count and can only get the string values for the posted file name from `Request.Form("upload") or Request.Item("upload")`

So how do you access the file data from a cross domain file post in classic ASP to ASP.NET?

Comment: Is this really a cross domain issue? you have the ASP pages delivered from a different DNS host name than the ASP.NET?

Comment: Yes the pages live on two different domain's say site.com and new.site.com. Optimally for the time being they can stay in that format until the owners decide to make the full switchover.  So therein lies my problem.

Comment: Still no luck posting the files from the asp site to the .net site.  I broke down and included an Iframe with some javascript to automatically submit the page when the file of the <input type="file"> is updated, and this works for now.  I"m still interested in the original query though if anyone has any thoughts.